# importing tablespace showing error 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Tags: mysql, xampp, mariadb

trying to recover innodb table from ibd file (576kb). this is the exact steps i do:

- getting create table query using mysqlfrm command
- create the table
- Alter Table discard tablespace
- moving the new tablespace to the db directory
- Alter Table import tablespace;

and i'm getting this error after minutes:

> ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query

My current SQL configuration:

```
 # Example MySQL config file for small systems.
#
# This is for a system with little memory (<= 64M) where MySQL is only used
# from time to time and it's important that the mysqld daemon
# doesn't use much resources.
#
# You can copy this file to
# C:/xampp/mysql/bin/my.cnf to set global options,
# mysql-data-dir/my.cnf to set server-specific options (in this
# installation this directory is C:/xampp/mysql/data) or
# ~/.my.cnf to set user-specific options.
#
# In this file, you can use all long options that a program supports.
# If you want to know which options a program supports, run the program
# with the "--help" option.

# The following options will be passed to all MySQL clients
[client]
# password       = your_password 
port=3306
socket="C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"


# Here follows entries for some specific programs 

# The MySQL server
default-character-set=utf8mb4
[mysqld]
port=3306
socket="C:/xampp/mysql/mysql.sock"
basedir="C:/xampp/mysql"
tmpdir="C:/xampp/tmp"
datadir="C:/xampp/mysql/data"
pid_file="mysql.pid"
# enable-named-pipe
key_buffer=16M
max_allowed_packet=16M
sort_buffer_size=512K
net_buffer_length=8K
read_buffer_size=131072K
read_rnd_buffer_size=512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size=8M
log_error="mysql_error.log"

# Change here for bind listening
# bind-address="127.0.0.1" 
# bind-address = ::1          # for ipv6

# Where do all the plugins live
plugin_dir="C:/xampp/mysql/lib/plugin/"

# Don't listen on a TCP/IP port at all. This can be a security enhancement,
# if all processes that need to connect to mysqld run on the same host.
# All interaction with mysqld must be made via Unix sockets or named pipes.
# Note that using this option without enabling named pipes on Windows
# (via the "enable-named-pipe" option) will render mysqld useless!
# 
# commented in by lampp security
#skip-networking
#skip-federated

# Replication Master Server (default)
# binary logging is required for replication
# log-bin deactivated by default since XAMPP 1.4.11
#log-bin=mysql-bin

# required unique id between 1 and 2^32 - 1
# defaults to 1 if master-host is not set
# but will not function as a master if omitted
server-id   =1

# Replication Slave (comment out master section to use this)
#
# To configure this host as a replication slave, you can choose between
# two methods :
#
# 1) Use the CHANGE MASTER TO command (fully described in our manual) -
#    the syntax is:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST=<host>, MASTER_PORT=<port>,
#    MASTER_USER=<user>, MASTER_PASSWORD=<password> ;
#
#    where you replace <host>, <user>, <password> by quoted strings and
#    <port> by the master's port number (3306 by default).
#
#    Example:
#
#    CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='125.564.12.1', MASTER_PORT=3306,
#    MASTER_USER='joe', MASTER_PASSWORD='secret';
#
# OR
#
# 2) Set the variables below. However, in case you choose this method, then
#    start replication for the first time (even unsuccessfully, for example
#    if you mistyped the password in master-password and the slave fails to
#    connect), the slave will create a master.info file, and any later
#    change in this file to the variables' values below will be ignored and
#    overridden by the content of the master.info file, unless you shutdown
#    the slave server, delete master.info and restart the slaver server.
#    For that reason, you may want to leave the lines below untouched
#    (commented) and instead use CHANGE MASTER TO (see above)
#
# required unique id between 2 and 2^32 - 1
# (and different from the master)
# defaults to 2 if master-host is set
# but will not function as a slave if omitted
#server-id       = 2
#
# The replication master for this slave - required
#master-host     =   <hostname>
#
# The username the slave will use for authentication when connecting
# to the master - required
#master-user     =   <username>
#
# The password the slave will authenticate with when connecting to
# the master - required
#master-password =   <password>
#
# The port the master is listening on.
# optional - defaults to 3306
#master-port     =  <port>
#
# binary logging - not required for slaves, but recommended
#log-bin=mysql-bin


# Point the following paths to different dedicated disks
#tmpdir = "C:/xampp/tmp"
#log-update = /path-to-dedicated-directory/hostname

# Uncomment the following if you are using BDB tables
#bdb_cache_size = 4M
#bdb_max_lock = 10000

# Comment the following if you are using InnoDB tables
#skip-innodb
innodb_data_home_dir="C:/xampp/mysql/data"
innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir="C:/xampp/mysql/data"
#innodb_log_arch_dir = "C:/xampp/mysql/data"
## You can set .._buffer_pool_size up to 50 - 80 %
## of RAM but beware of setting memory usage too high
innodb_buffer_pool_size=600M
## Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
innodb_log_file_size=600M
innodb_log_buffer_size=600M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=5
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=600
wait_timeout=600
innodb_file_per_table=5

## UTF 8 Settings
#init-connect=\'SET NAMES utf8\'
#collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci
#character_set_server=utf8
#skip-character-set-client-handshake
#character_sets-dir="C:/xampp/mysql/share/charsets"
sql_mode=NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
log_bin_trust_function_creators=1

character-set-server=utf8mb4
collation-server=utf8mb4_general_ci
[mysqldump]
max_allowed_packet=600M

[mysql]
# Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
#safe-updates

[isamchk]
key_buffer=20M
sort_buffer_size=20M
read_buffer=2M
write_buffer=2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer=20M
sort_buffer_size=20M
read_buffer=2M
write_buffer=2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
```

Error Message showing like this;

```
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2021-03-30 10:05:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2021-03-30 10:05:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-03-30 10:05:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-03-30 10:05:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-03-30 10:05:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2021-03-30 10:05:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2021-03-30 10:05:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2021-03-30 10:05:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=316759
2021-03-30 10:05:58 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting final batch to recover 1 pages from redo log.
2021-03-30 10:05:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2021-03-30 10:05:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2021-03-30 10:05:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-03-30 10:05:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-03-30 10:05:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-03-30 10:05:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2021-03-30 10:05:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.18 started; log sequence number 316788; transaction id 185
2021-03-30 10:05:59 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2021-03-30 10:05:59 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2021-03-30 10:05:59 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

Comment: You mean the MySQL server dies after a few minutes? Check the log file, it's usually located in the data folder with `*.err` file extension.

Comment: What does the server error log say?